# com.android.volley.AuthFailureError Using GET in StringRequest with Volley Library

Tags: php, android, kotlin, request

I´ve been trying to do a GET request to my php file using Volley Library. The problem I´m having is that I can´t stablish a connection with my URL. The error I´m getting is this one: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val tvResult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvResultado)
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "http://192.168.100.10:80/android_connect/get_all_products.php"
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, { response ->
        //val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
        //val jsonObject = jsonArray[0]
        Log.d("tag", "SI")
        //tvResult.text = jsonObject.toString()
    }
    , { error ->
            Log.d("tag", error.toString())

    })
    queue.add(stringRequest)


}
```

}

I´ve tried different approaches for this problem. I disabled my Windows Firewall, I tried using JSONObjectRequest instead of StringRequest, I already added the android.permission.INTERNET in my AndroidManifest aswell as adding the setting usesCleartextTraffic="true".
I also tried the request using postman, and I´m having a succesfull response:[Postman Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpoLD.png)

Also when I´m accessing the .php file from my browser I´m getting an effective response.

I also tried using another URL, like https://www.google.com/ and I´m having a successful connection when using the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s me again. I´ve solved my problem.
By default, XAMPP and WAMP Apache servers have a default configuration that doesn´t allow foreign access to your php files. The configuration can be modified in the following file (in WAMP): httpd-vhosts.conf.
This is how I accessed it:
[image]

The configurations contained in the file are the following:

[image]

By default, the setting **Require** is setted to **local**. For external access, that´s what the android app needs, it´s necesary to change it to **Require all granted**.
Therefore, this is how the config file should look:
[image]
This solved the problem for me.